# How to install AMD's graphics card RADEON HD 7470M Driver on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ati, radeon

My laptop is ASUS's X44H, with Intel® Core™ i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 , and AMD's graphics card RADEON HD 7470M. How I will install my graphics Driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the default drivers that come with the distro. Go to "Software & Updates" and under the tab "Additional Drivers" you'll find them.

Depending on you level of expertise, and for better results, I strongly recommend going to http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide